# Error: graphical parameter "type" is obsolete. when adding abline

Tags: r

Here's an example:

```
data = rnorm(100)
plot(data)
abline(h = 0,type = "1", lty = 3)
```

then an error occurs:

Warning message:
In int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) :
  graphical parameter "type" is obsolete

I basically want a dotted line at y=0.

Comment: It doesn't have `type` argument

Comment: `abline(h = 0, lty = 3)`

Comment: According to `?par` `lty- The line type. Line types can either be specified as an integer (0=blank, 1=solid (default), 2=dashed, 3=dotted, 4=dotdash, 5=longdash, 6=twodash) or as one of the character strings "blank", "solid", "dashed", "dotted", "dotdash", "longdash", or "twodash", where "blank" uses ‘invisible lines’ (i.e., does not draw them).`   So  you are already specifying `lty = 3`, not sure why you need  `type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `abline` doesn't have the `type` parameter.  Instead there are a list of graphical parameters including `lty` which would give the expected line.  According to `?par`

> lty- The line type. Line types can either be specified as an integer (0=blank, 1=solid (default), 2=dashed, 3=dotted, 4=dotdash, 5=longdash, 6=twodash) or as one of the character strings "blank", "solid", "dashed", "dotted", "dotdash", "longdash", or "twodash", where "blank" uses ‘invisible lines’ (i.e., does not draw them)

So, we just need to drop the `type` argument from `abline`

```
abline(h = 0, lty = 3)
```